# Valor de @@error en sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo este código para la creación de 3 tablas, y ha de hacerse de forma que o se hagan todas o ninguna :

```
DECLARE @ERROR INT

BEGIN TRANSACTION

CREATE TABLE PUBLICO (
    NUMPERSONA  INT   NOT NULL,
    ...
)

CREATE TABLE ASISTIR (
    IDRUTA      INT   NOT NULL,
    ...
)

CREATE TABLE RUTAS (
    IDRUTA      INT   PRIMARY KEY,
    ....
)

SET @ERROR=@@ERROR
    
IF @ERROR=0
COMMIT TRANSACTION

IF @ERROR!=0
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Mi pregunta es: la variable `@@error`, ¿recoge los errores del bloque de los 3 `CREATE TABLE` o solo recoge los del ultimo bloque? Y ¿seria mejor hacerlo así, o con un `TRY`-`CATCH`?

Answer (score 1):

La variable @@ERROR solo recoge los errores de la última instrucción. Pero desde la versión 2005 es mejor utilizar los bloques TRY...CATCH...

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  
BEGIN TRY  
    CREATE TABLE PUBLICO ( NUMPERSONA INT NOT NULL, ... );

    CREATE TABLE ASISTIR ( IDRUTA INT NOT NULL, ... );

    CREATE TABLE RUTAS ( IDRUTA INT PRIMARY KEY, .... ) ;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    -- Execute error retrieval routine.  
    SELECT  
         ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH;
```